# MVC web app is auto minimizing javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a project that just happens to be MVC and in Visual Studio 2010. (I don't know if that has anything to do with it, but I'm just trying to be specific in the problem) The issue is that when I build it it is auto minimizing the javascript and as such makes it really hard to debug.

I have looked at the build events and there are none.

I have looked for any vs extensions that could do this and I don't see any out of the ordinary.

I have edited the project file just to make sure nothing was hidden in it.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this behavior could be happening?

Comment: what do  mean by 'auto minimizing javascript'..?
Do you mean its minifying, or not adding..or....???

Comment: It is minifying the js automatically so that when I view it with Chrome developer tools or Firebug in Firefox or IE's developer tools everything is mashed together.

Comment: That isn't possible.  What are the URLs of the script tags? What server are you using?

Comment: Unless you have installed a plugin VS2010 doesn't minimize javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Does your site master just reference a minified js file instead of your development version of the js file?

Comment: No, it happens even with new js files that I create.  The only minified file in the project is jQuery and it is explicitly referencing that minified file, but I don't really care about the internal workings of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for trying to help.  I found it though.  Our company has created an HttpHandler that was configured in the web.config that causes this functionality.  I thought I had looked everywhere, but missed this as I was going through it.